# Allow a child thread to call a delegate to the parent when the parent is in a join state waiting on the child in c#

Tags: multithreading, delegates, deadlock

I have a form that is responsible for creating and setting up an instance of an object, and then telling the object to go do its work.  The process is a long one, so there's an area on the form where status messages appears to let the user know something is happening.  Messages are set with a setMessage(string msg) function.  To allow the form to remain responsive to events, I create a new thread for the object to run in, and pass it the setMessage function as a delegate to allow the object to set status messages on the form.  This part is working properly.  The main form is responsive and messages posted to its setMessage function appear as expected.

Because the process is a long one, and is made up of many steps, I want to allow the user to terminate the process before it's finished.  To do this I created a volatile bool called _stopRequested and a function called shouldStop() that returns its value.  This is also given to the object as a delegate.  The object can tell if it should terminate by checking shouldStop() periodically, and if it's true, shut down gracefully.

Lastly, Windows controls are not thread safe, so the compiler will complain if a thread other than the one that created the control tries to manipulate it.  Therefore, the setMessage function is wrapped in an if statement that tests for this and invokes the function using the parent thread if it's being called from the worker thread (see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for a description).

The problem arises when the user requests a shutdown.  The main form sets _stopRequested to true and then waits for the child thread to finish before closing the application.  It does this by executing _child.Join().  Now the parent thread (the one running the form) is in a Join state and can't do anything.  The child thread (running the long process) detects the stop flag and attempts to shut down, but before it does, it posts a status message by calling it's setMessage delegate.  That delegate points back to the main form, which figures out that the thread setting the message (child) is different than the thread that created the control (parent) and invokes the function in the parent thread.  The parent thread is, of course, in a Join state and won't set the text on the text box until the child thread terminates.  The child thread won't terminate because it's waiting for the delegate it called to return.  Instant deadlock.

I've found examples of signaling a thread to terminate, and I've found examples of child threads sending messages to the parent thread, but I can't find any examples of both things happening at the same time.  Can someone give me some pointers on how to avoid this deadlock?  Specifically, I'd like the form to wait until the child thread terminates before closing the application but remain able to do work while it waits.

Thanks in advance for the advice.

Comment: Join() in GUI event handler - classic Join-generated deadlock.  First approach to try - what happens if you just comment out the Join()?

Comment: Second approach - post another 'ThreadActionCompleted' delegate as the last line of your thread, (and, of course, dump the Join).

Comment: ..then try to forget you ever heard of Join()  :)

Comment: ..and don't wait on anything in a GUI event handler ever again :)

Answer (score 0):

1-(lazy) Dispatch the method from a new Thread so it doesn't lock

2-(re-think) The main UI thread should be able to control the child thread, so forget the _stopRequested and shouldStop() and implement a childThread.Abort() , abort does not kill the thread, but sends a [ThreadAbortException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) 
which can be handled or even canceled

```
catch(ThreadAbortException e)
{
    ReleaseResources();
}
```

Make the ReleaseResources safe by making various checks such as:

```
resource != null
```

or

```
resource.IsClosed()
```

The ReleaseResources should be called normally without abort and also by abort.

3-(if possible)stop the child, via main thread call ReleaseResources()

You may have to implement a mix of these.